# Electric field around a current carrying conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic

The picture shows the direction of the magnetic field around a current carrying wire. I wonder what will be the direction of the electric field with respect to the direction of the magnetic field ? I am trying to visualize both electric and magnetic field at the same time. I am getting the picture of the direction of the magnetic field everywhere but could not find any picture that shows both of them togather. So how the electric field around the moving charges will look like along with magnetic field ? 
[image]

Comment: voltage. electric field. but how the electric field around the moving charges will look like ?

Comment: This is a DC current? There's nothing in this situation that produces a significant E field, which explains why you've never seen the E field plotted.

Comment: Hi, Alex. Add that into your question rather than commenting on your own post. You need to make it into proper sentences though.

Comment: Electric field is inside the conductor aligned to the direction of the current.

Comment: Please don't cross-post on multiple SE sites. You already asked this 3 minutes earlier on Physics.SE ([link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411492/22927)). Wait for answers on one site (for, say, 24 hours), then if you are not satisfied, or want an answer from a different point of view, you can ask on a different site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how the electric field around the moving charges will look like along with magnetic field ?

Since the moving charges are electrons, the field they produce points radially toward the wire.

But remember there are also fixed charges inside the wire, and these exactly balance the moving charges (until you introduce something in your model to produce a capacitance between the wire and some other object), so that the net field due to the fixed and mobile charges is 0.

If the wire is a real (non-ideal) material, we know there is a small electric field axially along the wire that causes the current to flow. There will be a similarly small leakage of this field outside the wire. This field will point along the wire in the direction of current flow. But it is normally small enough to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

To find a figure that shows both electric and magnetic field
around a wire, search for 'Poynting vector'.   The electric field
in a current-carrying wire is axial, and also outside the
wire.

Electric power transmission (and power flow in general) is 
the vector cross product of these fields, both in wired and
wireless propogation.

The Wikipedia on 'Poynting vector' has a suitable illustration (the
fields are indicated around a resistor, but any conductor is similar).
[Poynting vector, E and B fields in current-carrying wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector)

Comment: can you just show any picture of the both fields togather ?

Comment: Have you looked up Poynting vector already and failed to find an image?

Comment: i will learn about poyenting vector but i need a short answer and image right now. can anyone please show me the image for now ? @Transistor

Comment: No. We are not here to do research or homework for you on demand. -1.

Comment: point-and-click...  it's in a picture, color-coded even, at the link @Whit3rd provided